# Switching a Flash Video player's color scheme based on set cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, cookies

Hey everyone, I've got a web site up and running that allows the user to choose a dark or light color scheme, thanks to earlier help from here at stackoverflow.

But on the project detail pages, there are Flash videos that also change slightly based on which color scheme is selected.

Example of a page is here:
http://centerline.net/projects/detail/?p=84

If you start playing the video, and change color schemes, the flash player will change to the right color, but on refreshing, it doesn't remember that change. How do I modify to code below so that the Flash player reads the correct color scheme and takes action?

Pertinant code is here (full JS file is here: http://www.centerline.net/lib/js/site-unmin.js):

```
//Switches color of Flash Video player on detail pages
function updateColor(color) {
//alert("called");
    var vidPlayers = document.getElementsByName("StageVideoPlayer");
    for(var i=0;i<vidPlayers.length;i++) {
        var player = vidPlayers[i];
        player.changePlayerColor(color);
    }
}  



//Swaps out style sheets for different designs. Sets cookie to remember user's design preference.
if($.cookie("css")) {       
    $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("css"));

}else if($.cookie("cssSession")) {
    $("link").attr("href",$.cookie("cssSession"));

}else{

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)

    if (rand > 0) {

       $("link").attr("href","/lib/css/common-dark.css");
       $.cookie("cssSessionColor","dark", {expires:null, path: '/'});
       $.cookie("cssSession","/lib/css/common-dark.css", {expires:null, path: '/'});


    }else{

       $("link").attr("href","/lib/css/common.css");
       $.cookie("cssSessionColor","light", {expires:null, path: '/'});
       $.cookie("cssSession","/lib/css/common.css", {expires:null, path: '/'});

    };
}



window.onLoad = function(){
    updateColor($.cookie("cssSessionColor"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the window.onLoad event is occurring before the video player is ready to receive ExternalInterface calls or register callbacks. I would suggest listening for the player to load within flash, check if ExternalInterface is available then call a JS function that returns the cookie info.

Comment: I'll have one of our Flash devs try that. Thanks.